# Component Exception : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.results.response.map') react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I want to iterate array which will repeat cards. I am getting response in which I have

```
{
  "get":"statistics"
  "parameters":{...}
  "errors":[]
  "results":1
  "response":[...]
}
```

I want to Iterate response and inside `response` I am trying to display `population`

Response Array (inside)

```
"response":[
  {
    "continent":"Oceania"
    "country":"Australia"
    "population":25842408
    "cases":{...}
    "deaths":{...}
    "tests":{...}
    "day":"2021-08-30"
    "time":"2021-08-30T06:45:03+00:00"
  }
]
```

When I try to display it in console it works and it display the population but when I use the `map()` function to repeat cards it gives error that undefined is not an object
where I am doing mistake

My class

```
export default class Covidscreen extends React.Component{
      
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      results :{},
      namee:'fahad',
    };
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Loginscreen',
    //Sets Header text of Status Bar
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
      //Sets Header color
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
      //Sets Header text color
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        //Sets Header text style
      },
  };
    
  getCovidData = () => {        
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      params: {country: 'australia'},
      url: 'https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics',
      headers: {
        'x-rapidapi-host': 'covid-193.p.rapidapi.com',
        'x-rapidapi-key': 'e4b2e7d44bmsh5427dd9c7fb16dbp15d226jsn1fdf62e5a45e'
      }
    };
            
    axios.request(options)
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({results:response.data});
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
         
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getCovidData()
  }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;    
    return (
      <View >
        { this.state.results.response.map(row => (          
          <Card > 
            <Card.Title>{row.population}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Divider/>
          </Card>
        ))}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I am using class based component and i have logged the response and it works there as i tried for loop and accessed population

Answer (score 1):

In the initial state, the `results` is an object which doesn't have the property `response` inside it. That is why you are getting the error  `Component Exception : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.results.response.map')`.

During the initial rendering, it is expecting the `results` object to have a property called `response` and it is expected to be an array (as you are calling the `map` function on it).

You can fix this issue in a lot of different ways,

1. Add a loading indicator state (based on this state and API response, render list)
2. Make the `results` state initially an array and then assign the response to it.
3. Make the `results` objects initially having a key `response` and initialize it with an array.

This list could go on and on...

The below code explains the second approach

```
export default class Covidscreen extends React.Component{
      
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      results: [], // changed the object to an array
      name: 'fahad',
    };
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Loginscreen',
    //Sets Header text of Status Bar
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
      //Sets Header color
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
      //Sets Header text color
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        //Sets Header text style
      },
  };
    
  getCovidData = () => {        
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      params: {country: 'australia'},
      url: 'https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics',
      headers: {
        'x-rapidapi-host': 'covid-193.p.rapidapi.com',
        'x-rapidapi-key': 'e4b2e7d44bmsh5427dd9c7fb16dbp15d226jsn1fdf62e5a45e'
      }
    };
            
    axios.request(options)
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({ results: response.data.response });
      // set the response array to the results state
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
         
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getCovidData()
  }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;    
    return (
      <View >
        { this.state.results.map(row => (          
          <Card > 
            <Card.Title>{row?.population ?? ''}</Card.Title> // added optional chaining. if the row doesn't have a population inside it, it will render an empty string.
            <Card.Divider/>
          </Card>
        ))}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Also on a totally different note, it would be better not to hardcode your API keys in your code.

Comment: It has response property in it in form of array

Comment: @MohammadFahad Yes, that is why we are setting the `results` with `response.data.response`. Now the `results` state will have the newly updated array from API.

Answer (score 0):

state results object to array because your API provides array data

```
this.state = {
      results :[],
      namee:'fahad',
 };
```

update loop

```
{this.state.results.map(row=>(
<Card > 
  <Card.Title>{row.population}</Card.Title>
  <Card.Divider/>
</Card>
  ))}
```

can you try this?

Answer (score 0):

In your first render, your state doesn't have a response property,
So, before you receive data from server, React is trying to map state.results.response, which is undefined.

So I suggest you define your initial state like this:

```
   this.state = {
      results :{response:[]},
      namee:'fahad',
    };
```

Comment: I have tried it but not working and i get same error it is the arrays name

Answer (score 0):

The map function is called before getCovidData returned the response data.
That’s why you need to ensure that this.state.results.response is filled with data.

```
this.state.results.response.map
```

You could initialize your state with an empty array:

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      results :{
        response:[]
      },
      name:'fahad', //Fix typo
    };
  }
```

Or check if response is already filled:

```
this.state.results.response && this.state.results.response.map
```

Comment: how can i fill it then or make it update as i "have" to  call  it when component is mounted

Comment: That is not necessary, when the axios request returned data and setState were called, a rerender with data will be trggered

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it by using call abck function when i am setting state

```
 this.setState({results:response.data},()=>{
            this.setCovid(this.state)
          });

  setCovid = (response) => {
        console.log(response);

      }
```

as it is asynchronous